# Suspend All Navigation Request

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

**Consider the following scenario:**

1. SCO A is launched,
2. SCO A sets its cmi.exit = suspend and then triggers a Continue navigation request,
3. SCO B is launched,
4. SCO B triggers a Suspend All navigation request and the learner returns to the LMS,
5. The learner triggers a Resume All navigation request,
6. SCO B is launched again,
7. SCO B triggers a Previous navigation request,
8. SCO A is launched.

**Question:** Now, should the Tracking Model and Run-Time Environment Data Model of SCO A be set to default or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracking data for both SCO A and SCO B is saved. In fact, `Suspend All` saves tracking dat for all SCOs in the course. On resuming, all tracking data for all SCOs is restored. Think of `Suspend All` as taking a snapshot to the whole course at the moment of returning to the LMS.